# Any nonabelian group of order 12 is isomorphic to A4, D6, or Z3 x Z4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Can someone show me the proof for :

> Any nonabelian group of order 12 is isomorphic to $D_6$, $A_4$, or $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$

I've seen a few proofs where this is included in also proving $A_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ but $D_6$ always seems to be left as an exercise.

Comment: Since the notation $D_n$ is sometimes used for the dihedral group with $n$ elements and sometimes for the symmetry group of the $n$-gon, and since you have order 12 in the title, but order 6 in the body, and since you seem to know a proof about $A_4$ - I am confused, please clarify your question

Comment: In the body it should have said order 12, thank you for pointing that out. The proof that I saw condensed the proof for A4, and 4 other groups, so I had a hard time following it.

Comment: Well, then the claim became false now: there are three *different* (up to isomorphism) groups of order $\;12\;$ , one of them being the dihedral one.

Comment: Isn't it about groups of order 6? Because I've seen various proofs of the statement: Non-abelian of order 6 is isomorphic to symmetric/dihedral, but for order 12 this is actually false.

Comment: @Joanpermo You mean there are three different *nonabelian* groups of order $12$. There are also two abelian groups.

Comment: Uhh....$\Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_4$ is abelian...

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice note on the classification of all groups of order $12$ by Keith Conrad [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/group12.pdf), see Theorem $1$. There are exactly three different non-abelian groups of order $12$, namely $A_4, D_6$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/4$. The proof uses, of course, Sylow theorems and an isomorphism property of semidirect products. Special attention also is paid to the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}/3 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/4$, which is the group you should take instead of the abelian direct product.